# Jmeter results average time shows more time (seconds) than the time shown in the server for processing the single request's time in the logs

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter results average time shows more time (seconds) than the time shown in the server for processing the single request's time in the logs.

The application server is Linux OS one.

Steps followed:
1. Run Jmeter test for single request from local system (Windows)
2. Observe logs in the server>Request shows as processing with time take to process the request
3. Run is completed in Jmeter> Observe the results> The avg/min/max time shows high than the actual time shown in the server logs for the same request.

Jmeter version: 3.1

Tried multiple times for the same scenario however unable to get similar results at both the places.

Please guide what could be gone wrong or the way needs to be tested or look at the results for analysis.

Comment: of course that the connect/read and processing the request on application server takes time, you should show more info

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Is it like something JMeter measures the time from when the request has just been sent until last byte of response received whereas the server logs shows only time server spent processing the request (not considering the until last byte of response recieved..)?

Comment: you pretty much sums it up correctly

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and guidance. You can put your comment as answer, will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server log you can calculate only time from receiving a message in your application level and until you return an answer,

JMeter calculate the `Load time` which include `Connect Time` (see below) and time reading and processing the response from server.

Your server can have in front of it firewall and/or load-balancer(s) and/or other proxy or other network components.

Inside your server you can have other processes as Apache and/or HTTP filter (s) that can also take time that you won't calculate in your logs.

Example of JMeter times (notice also Latency can be less than overall Load time):

```
Load time: 686
Connect Time: 219
Latency: 685
```